# How do I test for intersection between a ray and a cone?

Tags: java, intersection, raytracing

I decided that writing a ray-tracer in my game was a brilliant idea, and so now I am looking for code to use for ray to primitive intersection tests. I have based my effort on this very [nimble yet complete](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture20/RayTrace.java) code. It works well but only supports sphere primitives. I have added plane, disk and ring (in that order) because they are easy. Next I am thinking about adding box and cone.

But while sphere and plane intersection tests are really simple cone seems really difficult.

I have yet to find a simple and easy to adapt java implementation of a ray cone intersection test. I am in this to get a ray-tracer up and working quickly without learning too much math underway, so is does anyone have a java snippet lying around that performs a trivial ray cone intersection test suitable for a small ray-tracer?

Comment: I have written a script that does a Cone Cast in C# for Unity. If it would help, I'll post it. Let me know.

Comment: I have researched this further since i posted this Q and have come across the fact that cones represent a subset of another primitive type called "quadratic surface" which is usually used to handle cones in many ray-tracer implementations. I was planning on writing something about it once I got my head around it.

Comment: Yes C# implementation is welcome :)

Comment: Is there any way we could edit this to ask more generally about how ray–cone intersection works? “*Give a man a fish / teach a man to fish*”-style, it would be more useful.

Comment: Sometimes a man just wants a fish :D

Comment: Then go buy a fish.

Comment: When a user naively puts "ray-cone intersection java" into google, any more general question will not show up. Therefor IMO it is better to leave the ask naive so it can be found and make the answer more "learn-to-fish"-y. I have put my answer with this in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had some time to read up on this and decided to share.

In "serious" ray-tracers that grown-ups use, cones and other similar shapes such as cylinders are usually represented as either [tesselated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_(computer_graphics)) surfaces or as [quadric shapes](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node61.html). There exists pure cone-only intersection code that may or may not be more optimized, but implementing the more general quadric approach will give so much more value-for-effort for the beginner that it is worth implementing it first. Thus, in this answer I will focus on the quadric solution.

In geometry quadric shapes are

> any surface that can be defined by an algebraic equation of second
>   degree

. On the normal form this equation looks like this:

**A**x^2 + **B**y^2 + **C**z^2 +2**D**xy + 2**E**xz + 2**F**yz + 2**G**x + 2**H**y + 2**I**z + **J** = 0

By selecting different values for **A** through **J**, and by carefully applying axis aligned clipping planes in the right places, we can define what kind of surface we want. Here are some example shapes (from [here](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/9/9/6764/htm)):

[image: Different quadric shapes, including cone]

Finally to the code. Since my ray-tracer was based on the [ubiquitous instructional ray-tracer](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture20/RayTrace.java) by Leonard McMillan I found a plethora of student extensions more or less based on this code. One in particular  by a guy called Charlie had an implementation of `Ray-Quadric` intersection and shading code. I have shamelessly copied the important parts here (full code [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/admin/grading/assignments/ps5/M1-2/charlie/Quadric.java)), and will comment on it as soon as I get a chance to actually test it in my own application.

```
class Quadric extends Renderable {
    private static final float twoPI = (float)(Math.PI * 2.0);

    float A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J;
    float A2, B2, C2;
    float miny, maxy;
    Matrix3D OStoWS, WStoOS;
    float theta;

    public Quadric(Surface s, Matrix3D o2w, Matrix3D w2o, float zmin, float zmax, float thetamax,
                   float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g, float h, float i, float j ) 
    {
        surface = s;
        A = a; B = b; C = c; D = d; E = e; F = f; G = g; H = h; I = i; J = j;
        A2 = 2.0f * A;
        B2 = 2.0f * B;
        C2 = 2.0f * C;
        miny = -zmin - Constants.EPSILON; maxy = zmax + Constants.EPSILON;
        OStoWS = new Matrix3D(o2w);
        WStoOS = new Matrix3D(w2o);
        theta = (float)(thetamax * Math.PI / 180.0f - Math.PI);
    }

    Vector3D d = new Vector3D();
    Vector3D o = new Vector3D();
    float a2_1;
    float a, b, c, tOS, tWS, discrim;
    float dMagOS;

    public boolean intersect(Ray ray) {
        WStoOS.transform(ray.origin, o);
        WStoOS.transformNormal(ray.direction, d);
        dMagOS = 1.0f / d.length();  
        d.normalize();
        boolean flag = false;


        a = A * d.x * d.x + B * d.y * d.y + C * d.z * d.z;
        b = A2 * o.x * d.x + B2 * o.y * d.y + C2 * o.z * d.z;
        c = A * o.x * o.x + B * o.y * o.y + C * o.z * o.z + J;

        if (a == 0.0f) { 
            tOS = - c / b;
            flag = true;    // remember this
        } else {
            discrim = b * b - 4.0f * a * c; // compute discriminant

            if (discrim < 0.0f) return false; // no intersection

            discrim = (float)Math.sqrt(discrim);    // store sqrt value
            a2_1 = 1.0f / (2.0f * a);               // store 1 / (2a)
            tOS = (-b - discrim) * a2_1;            // near intersection

            if (tOS < 0.0f) {                       // near intersection too close
                tOS = (-b + discrim) * a2_1;        // use far intersection
                flag = true;                        // remember this
            }
        }

        tWS = tOS * dMagOS; // need to scale intersection tOS to get tWS
        if ((tWS > ray.tWS) || (tWS < 0)) return false;   // trivial reject

        ray.hitOS.addScaled(o, d, tOS); // get hit point in object space
        if (ray.hitOS.y < miny || ray.hitOS.y > maxy)   // outside clip box?
        {
            if (!flag) { // alright, so the near intersection is outside the clipping box,
                         // but that doesn't mean the far intersection isn't inside 
                tOS = (-b + discrim) * a2_1;    // compute the far intersection
                tWS = tOS * dMagOS;             // need to scale intersection t
                if ((tWS > ray.tWS) || (tWS < 0)) return false; // trivial reject

                ray.hitOS.addScaled(o, d, tOS);
                if (ray.hitOS.y < miny || ray.hitOS.y > maxy) return false;

            } else {    // both near and far intersection flunked clip box
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (theta != twoPI) {       // now clip against the accept angle
            float a = (float)Math.atan2(-ray.hitOS.z, -ray.hitOS.x);
            if (a > theta) {

                if (!flag) { // alright, so the near intersection is outside the accept angle,
                             // but that doesn't mean the far intersection isn't inside 
                    tOS = (-b + discrim) * a2_1;    // compute the far intersection
                    tWS = tOS * dMagOS;             // need to scale intersection t
                    if ((tWS > ray.tWS) || (tWS < 0)) return false; // trivial reject

                    ray.hitOS.addScaled(o, d, tOS); // update intersection point
                    a = (float)Math.atan2(-ray.hitOS.z, -ray.hitOS.x);
                    if (a > theta) return false;

                    // we haven't actually tested this yet at this point
                    if (ray.hitOS.y < miny || ray.hitOS.y > maxy) return false;

                } else {    // both near and far intersection flunked accept angle
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        ray.tWS = tWS;   
        ray.object = this;
        return true;
    }

    public void computeNormal(Ray ray) {
        Vector3D nOS = new Vector3D(
            A2 * ray.hitOS.x, 
            B2 * ray.hitOS.y,
            C2 * ray.hitOS.z);

        OStoWS.transformNormal(nOS, ray.n);
        ray.n.normalize();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my Cone Cast written in C# for Unity. It should be fairy simple to port to Java and adjust for your specific needs. It tests if a position is within the cone's volume. Hope it helps!

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class Vector3Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Casts a cone and checks if the target is within its volume. Parameters are the target position, the angle of the cone, the direction to cast the cone, and optionally, the range of the cone.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool ConeCast(this Vector3 vector3, Vector3 target, float degreeOfAccuracy, Vector3 direction, float range = Mathf.Infinity)
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(vector3, target) > range)
        {
            return false;
        }
        float actualAngle = Vector3.Dot(direction, target - vector3);
        float coneAngle = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * degreeOfAccuracy);
        return actualAngle >= coneAngle;
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, lemme know.

Comment: Disclaimer: I did some code cleanup on my phone just now, and I'm not sure which side of Ballmer's Peak I am on.